# Почему после попытки добавления второго элемента происходит ошибка mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, http-status-code-500

Почему-то могу добавить в коллекцию только один элемент, когда она пустая. Если в коллекции уже есть элемент, то новые почему-то не добавляются. Если отчистить коллекцию, то снова можно добавить только один элемент. В чем может быть дело?

```
const { Router } = require('express');
const Product = require('../models/Product');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth.middleware');
const router = Router();

router.post('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const { name, articul, measure, price, amount } = req.body;

      const product = new Product({
        userID: req.user.userId, name, articul, measure, price, amount
      });
 
      await product.save();
  
      res.status(201).json({ product });

  } catch(e) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова.' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: А текст-то ошибки вы и забыли показать.

Comment: @Yaant,
```
POSThttp://localhost:3000/api/arrival
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 149ms]
message "Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова."
e Object { index: 0, code: 11000, keyPattern: {…}, … }
index 0
code 11000
keyPattern Object { code: 1 }
code 1
keyValue Object { code: null }
code null
```

Comment: Не, это ошибка, которая вам на клиент возвращается из `catch`. А интерес тут представляет как раз исключение, из за которого этот `catch` срабатывает.

Comment: @Yaant,
 MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.products index: code_1 dup key: { code: null }
[0]   index: 0,
[0]   code: 11000,
[0]   keyPattern: { code: 1 },
[0]   keyValue: { code: null },
[0]   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}

Comment: @Yaant, хм, но я добавляю другие данный, отличные от тех, что я создал. Неужели монго генерирует повторно один и тот же _id?

Comment: У вас в модели есть поле `code`, судя по всему, объявленное как уникальное. А вы ему даже не пытаетесь задать какое-либо значение. В итоге оно становится `null`, и второй раз такой же `null` вставить не дает.

Comment: @Yaant, хм, очень странно. Я сначала хотел использовать поле code, но во время реализации передумал и убрал его еще до создания первых данных и по факту у меня его нет.
Сейчас попробовал заново очистить коллекцию, добавил в модель: code: { type: Number, unique: false, required: false }, и все равно добавился только один элемент в модель, при попытке добавить другие та же ошибка

Comment: тогда странно, да. Может, там когда-то индекс успел создаться у коллекции, и теперь ругается на несуществующее поле?

Comment: @Yaant, все, разобрался, спасибо вам большое! Видимо так и было, индекс вероятно создался, а удалял я элементы из коллекции, а не коллекцию, поэтому это не помогало. Удалил коллекцию целиком, пересоздал и все работает. Ура :)